# How to change order/location of HTML form elements in registration page of woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I added custom/extra user details in registration form of woocommerce (image attached ).[image]

**Fields shown in red box are custom fields.**

My code for add custom fields.

```
function My_extra_register_fields() {?>
   <br><hr>

   <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_password_again"><?php _e( 'Please Confirm Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="user_password_again" id="reg_password_again" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_dob"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="reg_customer_dob" id="reg_customer_dob"  />
    </p>
    
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_email_cnfrm"><?php _e( 'Please Confirm Email Address ', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_email_cnfrm" id="reg_billing_email_cnfrm"  />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Mobile', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone"  />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="reg_mkt_email" id=""  />Check 1
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="reg_mkt_number" id=""  />Check 2 
    </p>



    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'My_extra_register_fields' );
```

Now i am trying to change the order of all form elements in registration form. But issue is I can only change the order of customize elements add by me.I am not able to change the order of predefined elements (  Username,Email address & password) with custom elements.

**I am trying to achieve the following order -**

1. Username **(predefined)**
2. First Name
3. Last Name
4. Date Of Birth
5. Email Address **(predefined)**
6. Please Confirm Email Address
7. Password **(predefined)**
8. Please Confirm Password
9. Mobile Number

Any advice

Comment: You have to create your own form-login template that woocommerce to use. First form is located in my-account/form-login.php . Second one is in global/form-login.php . I would recommend using for Fnam Lnam Email and Phone to be billing_ prefix then customer will have autofilled fields on his order to save time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** check this [How to override WooCommerce template files?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256088/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files)

You have to override the form-login.php file.

```
`wp-content/pluings/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php`
```

Copy file from this path.

```
`wp-content/pluings/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php`
```

and upload this path.

```
`wp-content/themes/your-active-theme-name/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php`
```

Now you can edit this file and add your custom fields.

```
You can get the `$user` object to this file. and based on that you can get user meta.
```

Now replace this below HTML in `form-login.php` as per your requirements.

```
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-first">
<label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-last">
<label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="reg_dob"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="reg_customer_dob" id="reg_customer_dob"  />
</p>

<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
</p>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="reg_billing_email_cnfrm"><?php _e( 'Please Confirm Email Address ', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_email_cnfrm" id="reg_billing_email_cnfrm"  />
</p>

<?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
    </p>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="confirm_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="confirm_password" autocomplete="confirm-password" />
    </p>

<?php else : ?>

    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
<label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Mobile', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone"  />
</p>
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bhautik for your reply.It is working. Thanks :)